# Java stopping code execution?

Tags: java, if-statement, dead-code

I have a small chunk of code here, and it's called when somebody switches channels in TeamSpeak.  The `clid` is the user's ID, and the `cid` is the channel ID.  Integers `lobby` and `verified` are preset IDs representing the 'Tournament Lobby' and 'Name Verified' channels, and `reg` is a `Vector` of IDs to determine who is in the lobby.  the only other references to `reg` outside this function are its declaration and initialization.  Here's the code:

```
public void handleClientMove(int clid, int cid)
{
    String name = query.getClientNameFromID(clid);

    System.out.println(cid == lobby ? "lobby" : cid == verified ? "verified" : "non-tournament");

    if(cid == lobby)
    {
        System.out.println("Handling Tournament Lobby");

        if(!reg.contains(clid))
        {
            query.clientPoke(clid, "Welcome to the Tourney!  Please change your name to include your rank. ex: 'D5 Name', 'M1 Name2'");

            reg.add(clid);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(reg.contains(clid)) reg.remove(clid);
    }

    System.out.println("test01");

    if(cid == verified)
    {
        System.out.println("Handling Name Verified");

        if(!isUserRegistered(clid))
        {
            participants.add(new Player(name, clid, true));

            query.clientPoke(clid, "Your name has been verified and you are now entered in the tournament!");
        }
    }
}
```

The `println` statements are solely for debug purposes.  When I switch the channel to the lobby (I can validate that the correct `clid` and `cid` were passed in because of the debug statements) it works fine, but when I join the Name Verified channel (once again, proper parameters here) nothing happens.. at all.  the `println` statement at the top of the method runs, but the one between the `if` blocks is not, so it seems to me like something is preventing it from getting past the first block, even though it's not being run.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "verified" is being printed but "test01" is not, the program must therefore be stuck in an infinite loop inside `if(reg.contains(clid)) reg.remove(clid);`. If reg is of your class, debug it; if it is of a collections class, ensure that you are not improperly concurrently modifying it.

Comment: Thanks for the insight.  Turns out rather than requesting to remove the CLID itself from the array, I was only deleting the index (because CLID is an integer) and since only one CLID was in the array (index of 0) there was no index '1' to remove.  I have since fixed the problem by casting `clid` to an object.

Answer (score 0):

You should step through this with a debugger.  My guess is that the call to clientPoke() is blocking waiting on some network resource.

Comment: All `clientPoke()` does is send a telnet command upstream, so I highly doubt it.  Thanks for the idea of debugging though, it really helped. :D